# Delayed Chained Payment Using Adaptive Payments Issue

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I followed the [Paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/)

When i reach the  [4th step](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/0fb5qeizbe) i get [this](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0305qejfb1) error for payKey.

Comment: Is it possible to see the input parameters you pass for every call?

Comment: Have you check the status of the Payment details (step 3) ? It should showing as InComplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i managed to find the solution. In step-4 i wasn't passing the parameters correctly. WHen i closely looked at all parameters and made the call it works. Thanks to all who looked into the question and gave their time and comments.